# How to execute changes on remote server as root?

Tags: sudo, root

I'm wondering if there is a way to execute a script/commands from the the local machine without making any modifications as root on the remote machine?

**Some background**

I'm trying to setup some tasks via Capistrano and I require `sudo` access. There are about 30+ servers and for me to manually update `/etc/sudoers` will be painful so I was wondering if there is a method to update this file remotely?

Comment: You can use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) that has remote interaction. You can do the same with no interaction in parallel using `fabric.contrib.files.sed` method.

Comment: If you have 30 servers you're managing I highly recommend [SaltStack](https://saltstack.com/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can run local scripts remotely by executing `bash` on the remote system and feeding it your script

`$ ssh user@host 'bash -s' < script.sh`

**Edit**

To execute commands that require using `sudo` on a remote machine use `ssh's` `-t` option and pass the commands to `ssh`. The `-t` option allocates a [psuedo tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal) and enables user interaction with the commands ran by `ssh`, such as entering a password for `sudo`

```
$ ssh user@host -t 'sudo foo'
```

To modify a file using this method `sed` is recommended over a redirect `>` because shell redirection does not allow for writing files when using `sudo`.  Additionally, all variables in the `sed` command need to be escaped when they are passed to `ssh`.

```
$ ssh user@host -t 'sudo sed -i "\$a text to insert" /path/to/file'
```

To automate the whole thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVERS=( server1 server2 server3 )

for HOST in ${SERVERS[@]}; do 
    ssh user@${HOST} -t 'sudo sed -i "\$a text to insert" /path/to/file'

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: $HOST did not complete"
     else   
        echo "$HOST complete"
    fi   
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the script and all but it doesn't really answer my question. If I wish modify the `/etc/sudoers` file due to root permissions it will fail.

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan see edits to the answer

Comment: Hi, even that prompts for a `sudo` password which from what I understand is set in `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan If your account doesn't have `sudo` rights on these machines, then to modify `/etc/sudoers` you're going to have to login via ssh as `root`.  So the command would be `ssh root@host -t 'sed -i "\$a text to insert" /path/to/file'`

Comment: root ssh login is disabled by default so its not an option. I think I may be asking for the impossible.

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan yep that's how it's starting to sound

Answer (score 1):

I found the `tee` command to be helpful in avoiding the sudo limitation on file redirection. Using sed proved frustrating due to character escaping requirements.

This is the command I used to remotely append the hosts for all machines in my cluster to /etc/hosts:

```
for i in {1..10}; do ssh ubuntu@10.1.1.$i -t "echo '10.1.1.1 dev-1    
10.1.1.4 dev-4
10.1.1.3 dev-3
10.1.1.2 dev-2
10.1.1.6 dev-6
10.1.1.8 dev-8
10.1.1.5 dev-5
10.1.1.10 dev-10
10.1.1.9 dev-9
10.1.1.7 dev-7' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts >/dev/null"
```

The output for each iteration looks like this:

```
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
255 bytes (255 B) copied, 4.1338e-05 s, 6.2 MB/s
```

This SU answer was pivotal in building my final solution: https://superuser.com/a/1026359/587485

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run multiple commands or redirects you should use the following syntax:

```
ssh server.com "sudo sh -c 'ps aux | grep jav > /root/1.txt'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to already have some sort of root level access, either via direct root passwd or your user id sudo rule setup prior to attempting to modify the sudoers file.